# Shell Bash: How to prompt a user to select from a dynamically populated list?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

newbie here!

On a Shell Script (bash), after prompting user for name/password the script should read from a server.list and generate option for selection.

How do I provide the user the options from server.list like so:

```
#Please select from the server list:  

1) 10.1.1.xx

2) 10.1.1.xx

3) 10.1.1.xx

Select option [1]:
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have `dialog` installed on the user machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposing this *source* file:

```
$ cat server.list 
10.1.1.xx
10.1.2.xx
10.1.3.xx
```

Short answer:

```
select ip in $(cat server.list); do 
   echo $REPLY $ip
done
```

**Demo**

```
$ select ip in $(cat server.list); do echo $REPLY $ip; done
1) 10.1.1.xx
2) 10.1.2.xx
3) 10.1.3.xx
#? 1
1 10.1.1.xx
#? 2
2 10.1.2.xx
```

You will have to implement a `case` *loop* to do something useful with the `ip` variable.

**Example**

```
select ip in $(cat server.list) exit; do 
   case $ip in
      exit) echo "exiting"
            break ;;
         *) echo ip $ip;
   esac
done
```

Answer (score 6):

Since an answer already covers how to accomplish this using Bash's `select` here are two other options.

## 1. Plain POSIX shell

The following is how you can implement presenting the user with a choice of one option from a list of options in a POSIX shell script without relying on Bash's extensions.

### Code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Please select from the server list:'
nl server.list
count="$(wc -l server.list | cut -f 1 -d' ')"
n=""
while true; do
    read -p 'Select option: ' n
    # If $n is an integer between one and $count...
    if [ "$n" -eq "$n" ] && [ "$n" -gt 0 ] && [ "$n" -le "$count" ]; then
        break
    fi
done
value="$(sed -n "${n}p" server.list)"
echo "The user selected option number $n: '$value'"
```

### A sample interaction

```
Please select from the server list:
     1  10.1.1.1
     2  10.1.1.2
     3  10.1.1.3
     4  10.1.1.4
     5  10.1.1.5
Select option: 0
Select option: -1
Select option: w
list.sh: line 9: [: w: integer expression expected
Select option: 3
The user selected option number 3: '10.1.1.3'
```

## 2. Using dialog(1)

If you have [`dialog(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) installed on the user's machine you can present the user with pseudographical menu.

### Code

```
#!/bin/sh
tempfile="$(mktemp)"
while true; do
    dialog --menu 'Please select from the server list' 18 70 15 $(nl server.list) 2>"$tempfile" && break
done
n="$(cat "$tempfile")"
value="$(sed -n "${n}p" server.list)"
rm "$tempfile"
echo "The user selected option number $n: '$value'"
```

### Screenshot

[image: The dialog running in a terminal]

Comment: Awesome example! Just a little jotting, using prompt for read does not work on POSIX sh.

Answer (score 0):

Or based on @nwk's answer, but using a for loop and getting the output from another command (where `get_server_ips` is a command that returns a list of IPs):

```
echo 'Please select from the IP list:'
ips=$(get_server_ips)
echo -e "$ips" | nl;
count="$(echo -e "$ips" | wc -l)"
read -p 'Select option: ' n
for i in `echo -e "$ips" | nl`;
do
    if [ "$n" == "$i" ]; then
        value=$(echo -e "$ips" | sed -n ${i}p) 2>&1
        break
    fi
done;
echo "The user selected option number $n: '$value'"
```